# nested overloaded operators?

Tags: c++

Is nesting overloaded operators possible ? I would like to nest << inside a ()

```
template<class T>
struct UnknownName
{
   T g;
   T&operator<<(std::ostream&os, const T&v){return os<<v;}
   bool operator()(const T&v)
   {
      if(v==g)
        //do the streaming << then return true
      else return false;
   }
};
```

Would you please help me out ? I am afraid my example is unreal enough to you, please just ask if you still have any doubts. Sincerely.

Comment: You have to have your `operator<<` outside the class as a non member function.

Comment: `operator<<` is a binary operator, so your example has too many arguments (the `std::ostream`, the `const T&`, and the receiver object, `UnknownName<T>`. Do you want to invoke `operator<<` on the `UnknownName<T>` object or the `const T&` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can think of would be to have `operator<<` return a specific type, and then overload `operator()` to accept that type:

```
#include <cstdio>

namespace {
    struct Foo {
        struct Bar {
            int i;
        };

        Foo& operator()(const Bar& b)
        {
            std::printf("bar, %d\n", b.i);
            return *this;
        }

        // obviously you don't *have* to overload operator()
        // to accept multiple types; I only did so to show that it's possible
        Foo& operator()(const Foo& f)
        {
            std::printf("foo\n");
            return *this;
        }
    };

    Foo::Bar operator<<(const Foo& f, const Foo& g)
    {
        Foo::Bar b = { 5 };
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo f, g, h;
    f(g << h);
    f(g);
}
```

This isn't a common idiom, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell what you're asking, but I assume you mean write a class to the `ostream&` that gets passed to `operator<<`. First you have to make up a way to convert a `T` to a string representation. I'll assume the function `TToString` does that.

```
template<class T>
struct UnknownName
{
   T g;

   bool operator()(const T&v)
   {
      if(v==g) {
        cout << v;
        return true;
      }

      return false;
   }

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& v) {
      return os << TToString(v);
   }
};
```

Sorry if I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement `TToString`. As long as `operator<<` is defined for type `T`, using `os << v;` is fine (for example, if `T` is an `int`, etc.).

Comment: @Toolbox this is defining `operator<<` for `T`. So you have to turn `T` into a string so you don't get infinite recursion.